# Is it permissible for a Muslim man to marry a Christian woman who has a non-religious tattoo? (Sunni viewpoint)

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, sunni

If there is a Christian woman who has a tattoo (not of a religious nature), can a Muslim man still marry her?  Assume she does not want to convert but is a Christian (and repents).

I know a tattoo is haram because you are altering Allah's magnificent creations, but in this situation, is it ok for them to get married?

Sunni school of thought.

Comment: No offense (this is my opinion) why should marrying a women be haram if she has a tattoo? And with "women" I mean any regardless the religion. A tattoo in worst case can be removed. So how can a tattoo have any influence on a marriage? I mean the only thing that is relevant is that she might be sinning by having a tattoo, but this is absolutely irrelevant, as it is something between her and her Creator!

Comment: @Medi1Saif - very good point. It's just because Allah has said that he curses women and men with tattoo's. Of course, if the person has tattoo's and then reverts to Islam then all sins are forgiven (but must be following Islam!). This person in particular had realised that she did the wrong thing and has repented sincerely a long time ago and understood it was a mistake. Repentance is good but makes me wonder what the situation is if she has the tattoo but not converting to Islam. I guess trying to find out what is halal/haram in these situations

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Islam is also quite clear that people who are Jews or Christians despite having learned about islam enough and without too much bias will go to hell forever. If that is not an issue for marriage (although I personally can't see how you could be content in your heart with believing your spouse will suffer eternal punishment) legally in islam, then a tattoo certainly isn't.

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas This is not the answer just a comment why prefer to marry a christian when there are so many muslim women around ,the incident happened in US that a man married a christian woman after he passed away that lady didnt even allow the funeral prayer because she wanted to do in her own way,funeral prayer is very important in Islam the dead could be forgiven by Allah swt with that prayer.

Comment: I am talking from the SUNNI School of thought. I didn't think it would have mattered but interesting to know there are different views

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones - this is an old post. Why are you replying to this? Furthermore it seems that you/other members are trying to stop genuine questions being asked which is not the right thing to do in Islam! If one does not know, they seek knowledge from sources - wherever they may well be. DO NOT stop people from asking questions about Islam, regardless if you are an expert yourself. Contribute, don't be part of a problem and block people and shut them down. This is not permitted in Islam in any event.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I'm striving to reduce the number of unanswered questions, see e.g.: [We just hit 87% answered!](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3308).  [Jon Ericson ♦](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1700) mentioned unanswered questions is one thing holding back the site from graduating.  This question is one of [many similar questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3305) that are cluttering the site.  I encourage you to [edit] to improve the question to attract answers.  Also, consider raising your concerns on [meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/).